# PHP REGEX find & replace patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Trying to construct a regex that will locate a pattern of ANY character followed by double quotes

This regex locates each occurrence properly

```
(\S"")
```

Given the example below

```
$string='"WEINSTEIN","ANTONIA \"TOBY"","STILES","HOOPER \"PETER"","HENDERSON",';
$pattern = '(\S"")';
$replacement = '\\""';
$result=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

My result turns out to be

```
"WEINSTEIN","ANTONIA \"TOB\"","STILES","HOOPER \"PETE\"","HENDERSON"
```

But I am seeking

```
"WEINSTEIN","ANTONIA \"TOBY\"","STILES","HOOPER \"PETER\"","HENDERSON"
```

I understand the replacement is removing/replacing the whole match, but how can I remove all but the first letter rather than completely replacing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your pattern to use a positive lookbehind instead so that it doesn't capture the non-space character:

```
$string='"WEINSTEIN","ANTONIA \"TOBY"","STILES","HOOPER \"PETER"","HENDERSON",';
$pattern = '/(?<=\S)""/';
$replacement = '\\""';
$result=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $result;
```

Output

```
"WEINSTEIN","ANTONIA \"TOBY\"","STILES","HOOPER \"PETER\"","HENDERSON",
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/crop3)